# Magento deletes article after change on individual options

Tags: php, magento

A Magento 1.6 installation is deleting an article, when I change something in the individual options of a store view.

The exact procedure:

1. Open the article
2. Switch to a store view
3. Switch to individual options
4. Uncheck "Use default value" on an options.

Upon save, the article is gone.

More exactly: It deletes the attribute with id `273` (status). When I manually do this SQL the article is back up:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_int SET entity_type_id=10, attribute_id=273, store_id=0, entity_id=507, value=1;
```

(Where entity_id is the id of the lost article).

When I restore the article, it's gone after save again, even if i recheck the default option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Appears some useful information in the logfiles?

Comment: It says `ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: optionTypeId  in /.../app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Option/Value.php on line 230`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really getting it, but:

```
if ($result &&
            ($attribute->isScopeStore() || $attribute->isScopeWebsite()) &&
            !$this->_isAttributeValueEmpty($attribute, $value) &&
            $value == $origData[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] &&
            isset($origData['store_id']) && $origData['store_id'] != $this->getDefaultStoreId()
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        /* +++ THIS IS NEW +++ */
        if ($value === FALSE) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        /* ^^^ THIS IS NEW ^^^ */
```

... fixed it. Somehow the original if should have returned it - but it doesn't.